# Javascript : Creating a dynamic table with column title on the first row and row title in the first column

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a table with title to be displayed on the first and second row and first column. The first row will have the same name which is working fine. But with my below script the row title (starting from 3rd row) displays in the last column than the first.

Please advise where am I going wrong with this.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var yardName = "B1";
var colsInYard = 5;
var rowsInYard = 5;
var tbl = document.createElement("table");
tbl.setAttribute("id", "our_table");
var tblHead = document.createElement("thead");
for (var r = 0; r < 1; r++) {
  // creates a table row
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  for (var c = 0; c <= colsInYard; c++) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    if (c != 0) {
      var cellText = document.createTextNode(yardName);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    } else {
      var cellText = document.createTextNode(" ");
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
  }
  tblHead.appendChild(row);
}
for (var r = 0; r < 1; r++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  for (var c = 0; c <= colsInYard; c++) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    if (c != 0) {
      var cellText = document.createTextNode(c);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    } else {
      var cellText = document.createTextNode(" ");
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }

  }
  tblHead.appendChild(row);
}
tbl.appendChild(tblHead);
var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
for (var r = 1; r <= rowsInYard; r++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode(r);
  for (var c = 0; c <= colsInYard; c++) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.appendChild(cellText);

    row.appendChild(cell);
  }
  tblBody.appendChild(row);
}
tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
body.appendChild(tbl);
tbl.setAttribute("border", "0");
tbl.setAttribute("cellpadding", "0");
tbl.setAttribute("cellspacing", "0");
```

My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/udopgxLv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to add an IF statement to the code in the tbody section to get the data to post into the first column. I modified your jfiddle with the code below (just 2 lines added) and the values are inserted properly.

```
            for (var r = 1; r <= rowsInYard; r++) {
              var row = document.createElement("tr");
              var cellText = document.createTextNode(r);
              for (var c = 0; c <= colsInYard; c++) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                if (c==1){                        // <--- this was added 
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                 }                              // <--- this was also added

                row.appendChild(cell);
              }
              tblBody.appendChild(row);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You missed if statement in create tbody

```
 for (var c = 0; c <= colsInYard; c++) {
       var cell = document.createElement("td");
       if (c=== 0)
       cell.appendChild(cellText);

       row.appendChild(cell);
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/udopgxLv/3/

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.